# Content Security Policy and slickgrid

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, slickgrid

I am trying to add CSP header on a project that depends on the slick grid (slickgrid.js) . I think lines such as the following are causing issues:

```
$focusSink = $("<div tabIndex='0' hideFocus style='position:fixed;width:0;height:0;top:0;left:0;outline:0;'></div>").appendTo($container)
```

This is the error I am getting on the browser:

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
```

I tried the sha256- but it doesn't help as these are style attributes. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

To allow *style=* attributes it need to use 'sha256-...' together with `'unsafe-hashes'` token. It is supported in Chrome and Firefox, but [not in Safari](https://csplite.com/csp/test296/#bug_Safari_unsafe-hashes).

Therefore as for now you have no much choice other than to use 'unsafe-inline' in the `style-src` directive. Moreover, if many different style = '...' are used, it is unrealistic to collect all their hashes and keep them up to date.

The best what you can do is a CSP like that:

```
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src-attr 'unsafe-inline'; style-src-elem 'self';
```

At least Chrome users will be protected against XSS injection of `<style>..</style>` because of `style-src-elem 'self'` will apply in Chrome. Safari and Firefox will use `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` rule.

Alternatively you can rewrite JS code for using `class=''` instead of `style=''`, or use JS constructs like `Element.style.properrty = 'display:none';` which are not require `'unsafe-inline'` token.